# Item level permissions based on claim values

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, claims-based-auth, adfs

is it possible to have a SharePoint group that is based on a claim?

i.e, I have an ADFS enabled site.

One of the claim descriptions http://temp.org/Country has values like US, UK, India, etc..

Is it possible to have item level permissions on a list, solely based on the values of the claims, i.e. one list item should be visible only to users with Claim value US, the second only to users with Claim value UK, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

It definitely is possible to have item level permissions based on a claim just like you ask.

However, please consider the performance impact as this is "Fine Grained Permissions" and is one of the things to avoid if at all possible. Read this excellent [Best practices for using fine-grained permissions in SharePoint Server 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg128955.aspx) guide on technet. I recommend you try and architect the solution so you're not using FGP.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How else would you approach in this scenario?